# Django. DEBUG in production

Tags: python, django, django-deployment

I'm writing my first *real* project in Django and I have a problem with properly setting `DEBUG` in development and production. In my `settings.py` project file I have:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'True') == 'True'
```

So I expect that it should work as follows. By default `DEBUG` is set to `True` (I use this in my development). But on my production server I have an environmental variable `DJANGO_DEBUG` set to `"False"` so Django should set `DEBUG` to `False`.

But this does not work! When I go to `my_website/notexistingurl` I see Django detail error page which says that I have `DEBUG` set to `True` in my `settings.py` file. And to make this completely unclear to me, when I open a python shell on my server it says that `os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'True') == 'True'` is `False`.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing? Because to me it looks like two completely contradictory things!

Comment: Do you by any chance set a variable with WSGI?

Comment: A server often runs with a *different* user, this to avoid people that might take over the webserver from accessing all your files. So it is not because you set a path for *your* user, that it is also for the webserver user.

Comment: That being said, it might be better to implement it the opposite way, so `DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'False') == 'True'`, such that you run in debug mode when explictly set, right now you only run in production when explictily set, but that is more risky.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem. I think I know now what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a guess, but normally the Django server will *not* run under the same user as the "administrator". Indeed, as an extra security measure often such processes run under a *separate* user with limited privileges.

The aim is to prevent users that somehow can inject code in your Django application to gain more control. Indeed, imagine that a hacker found a way to evaluate arbitrary Python code by the Django server, then that hacker could eventually get control to all thinks the user that is running the Django app has control over such as files, devices, internet connections, etc. To limit this, often the Django app will run with a user that has that much privileges necessary to run the Django app, but not (much) more than that. While there might still be exploits to perform [*privilege escalation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation), this will at least make it more difficult and time-consuming.

This thus means that the environment of the user with which you are setting up the Django app, is not the user that *runs* the Django app, and therefore the environment variable probably is not set for that user. There is no universal way to solve this, since this likely depend on your hosting provider, but (very) likely there are ways to set environment variables for the django app user.

But nevertheless, it might be better to "reverse" the setting: right now you run in debug mode by default, and only in production when explicitly set. That is more risky, since things could get wrong when setting the environment variable, or deploying the application. When the Django app runs in debug mode it shows fragments of the source code, and one perhaps can manipulate the view that serves static/media files to serve more sensitive files. It might be better to run by default in production mode, and only run in debug mode when explicitly stated. For example with:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'False') == 'True'
```

Answer (score -2):

You should run

```
heroku config:set "Set DEBUG VALUE"
```